# Can FIFinderSync Extension and FileProvider Extension run together on XPC?

Tags: macos, xpc, findersync, nsxpcconnection, fileprovider-extension

I am trying to use FIFinderSync Extension to show Finder Overlays.
I also have FileProvider Extension that uses other Overlays.

Both uses XPC to communicate from the same parent app.

Both are built into separate .appex files. Both work well alone.
But when both are there in the Contents/PlugIns/ path, only one of them work.

The plists look like this

So my doubts are:

1. Can we have these two together?
2. Can two xpc work together?

Or, what am I missing or not doing correct?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

macOS assumes that your File Provider Extension replaces your Finder Sync Extension. When the system detects a (non-hidden) file provider domain from an extension inside the same app bundle as your Finder Sync Extension, it automatically transfers the "user opted in" status of your FSE to your FP domains.

We worked around this issue by wrapping the Finder Sync Extension into another app that we bundled with our main app. This way we could still have both extensions working.